# Links to questions in Area 51 Commitment Phase Don't Work (for me at least)

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, commitment-phase

**Yay!** It works now (for me)...I just kept clicking through the links, and eventually it worked...I feel like a crazy person.  But, apparently at least on other is seeing this behavior.

[They](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=commitment) just take you to a generic error page.

The following is the link to the top voted on-topic question, it is broken for me:

> [How do I delete my  account?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/707#707)

Also, the [tab](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=definition) to go look at the discussion phase is also broken.

**Update:** I switched browsers to Internet Explorer.  I had never been to Area 51 in IE.  The links worked while I was not logged in, but after I logged in, they broke in IE as well.

It works logged out in chrome, and then breaks again when I log back in.

Comment: `[status-norepro]` for me.

Comment: @Dr. Gonzo, does this link work?  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications/707#707

Comment: @jinguy: Yep. Takes me to "How do I delete my <social network> account?" Has 31 votes as of right now.

Comment: @Dr. Gonzo, Hmm, that's odd.  I get a picture of a cat using a toy computer...

Comment: @jinguy: Clear your cache and reload, maybe?

Comment: @Dr. Gonzo It must be some other issue.  It worked in IE when I wasn't logged in, but then broke again after I logged in.

Comment: Another "works for me" here too.

Comment: Works here too.  It's Monday.  You must need to go home now.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I just get the cat.

Comment: @Lance, hahaha.  Feel my pain...

Comment: The cat says it's his fault.

Comment: Now reopened. I'm going to clean up my comments in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not crazy! To repro this crash you must have

1. followed the proposal
2. committed to the proposal
3. sorted the example questions by "my votes"

That said, it should be fixed now, so hopefully you can't repro it any more.

Thanks @jjinguy, and also thanks to the ~3 other people who triggered the crash, which made it easier to spot the pattern in the error log.

Comment: Oh, so when I went to a site that hadn't been to proposal yet, and changed the sort order of the questions, I fixed it for myself?

Comment: Yea, it's likely that it stopped crashing after you changed the sort order while viewing a different proposal.